How to prevent Dataset to format list values?
How to prevent Dataset to format my values automatically? I prefer the original list format as it takes much less space than the grid format. As you can see from these examples, the condition when a list is formatted as a grid is not trivial.
Is it possible to do it in general (preferably as SetOption[Dataset, ...] or via an internal variable Block[{internal`private`secret`gridDisplayLimit = Infinity), Dataset[...]], see here) so that one does not have to wrap each column manually into HoldForm?
Dataset@{
  <|"Name" -> 1, "Deleted" -> {1, 2, 3}, "Added" -> {1, 2, 3, 4}|>,
  <|"Name" -> 2, "Deleted" -> {1, 2, 3, 4}, "Added" -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}|>}


Dataset@{
  <|"Name" -> 1, "Deleted" -> {1, 2, 3}, "Added" -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}|>,
  <|"Name" -> 2, "Deleted" -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, "Added" -> {1, 2, 3, 4}|>}


Dataset@{
  <|"Name" -> 1, "Deleted" -> {1, 2, 3}, "Added" -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}|>,
  <|"Name" -> 2, "Deleted" -> {1, 2, 3, 4}, "Added" -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}|>}



You can prevent the formatting using "HoldForm":
Dataset@{<|"Name" -> 1, "Deleted" -> {1, 2, 3}, 
   "Added" -> HoldForm@{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}|>, <|"Name" -> 2, 
   "Deleted" -> {1, 2, 3, 4}, "Added" -> HoldForm@{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}|>}


Actually a single HoldForm will do.

Ah yes, forgot to add that I want to prevent in general, so that I do not have to form ALL columns to something like HoldForm.

As I already mentioned, already a single HoldForm does the trick.

Do you mean it as wrapping a single value into HoldForm? It is certainly not enough, see Dataset@{<|"Name" -> 1, "Deleted" -> HoldForm@Range@8, "Added" -> Range@8|>, <|"Name" -> 2, "Deleted" -> Range@8,     "Added" -> Range@8|>}. It also introduces the additional problem of not evaluating values that should be, so I don't think it is robust enough.

You need the HoldForm once in every column. And do not use it on code that needs evaluation.

While this should be a customizable feature of Dataset from the user side, it is not, annoyingly, among other formatting quirks. I have argued previously that functionality and form should be separate in Dataset, so there should be something like a DatasetForm. Until that, I accepted your solution as the next best thing.

dset =
  Dataset[{
    <|"Name" -> 1, "Deleted" -> {1, 2, 3}, "Added" -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}|>,
    <|"Name" -> 2, "Deleted" -> {1, 2, 3, 4}, "Added" -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}|>}];

Query[All, <|
   "Name" -> #Name, 
   "Added" -> Row[#Added, ","], 
   "Deleted" -> Row[#Deleted, ","]|> &] @ dset



See edit please!

I see what you mean. I encountered this problem quite often, and never found a general solution. Unfortunately, the ItemSize- option doesn't help here.
